# Best way to structure AJAX for a Zend Framework application

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I thought of having an AJAX module service layer, with controllers and actions that interact with my model.  Easy, but not very extensible and would violate DRY.  If I change the logistics of some process I'll have to edit the AJAX controllers and the normal controllers.

So ideally I would load the exact same actions for both javascript and non-javascript users.  I have thought about maybe checking for `$_POST['ajax']`, if it is set I would load a different (json'y) view for the data.  Was wondering how/a good way to do this (front controller plugin I imagine?) or if someone can point me to an UP TO DATE tutorial that describes a really good way for building a larger ajax application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually use the request object to determine if a request has happened through ajax, e.g.:

```
// from your controller
if($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    // an ajax request, do something special (e.g. render partial view)
} else {
   // render entire view
}
```

That's basically testing for the `x-requested-with` header (which is not *always* present, depending on JS library, etc). See (under the heading of 'detecting ajax requests'):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html

Comment: `getRequest` should be `getRequest()`

Comment: @karim79 You think that a module only to receive ajax requests is a good pratice?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for XmlHttpRequest headers. Not all Javascript libraries do this, though, and even the ones that do don't necessarily do it in all browsers.

There's also [AjaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html), which basically checks the "context" request variable similar to your idea of $_POST['ajax'].

What I actually ended up doing was similar to your original suggestion. I created an AJAX module. In order to prevent tons of controller code duplication, I created a service layer that handles all the operations on models, so my controllers are really only responsible for transforming input requests and display.